# Interpretation of lavaan growth covariate parameters (effects on intercept and slope)

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, predictor, lavaan

I am trying to interpret the output of the growth command with regressors. Here's the command, and the covariates are dummy coded 0/1:

```
   # intercept and slope with fixed coefficients
    i =~ 1*G3_Theta_Read + 1*G6_Theta_Read + 1*G10_Theta_Literacy
    s =~ 0*G3_Theta_Read + 1*G6_Theta_Read + 2*G10_Theta_Literacy 

   # regressions
 i ~ Low_or_at_risk_LangCog  +SES+EDI_lang+ EDI_egender + G3_Background_BornOutside
 s ~ Low_or_at_risk_LangCog  +SES+EDI_lang+ EDI_egender + G3_Background_BornOutside
 '

fit <- growth(model, data = X2)
```

Output:

```
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  i ~                                                 
    Lw_r_t_rsk_LnC   -0.771    0.010  -74.558    0.000
    SES               0.156    0.008   18.581    0.000
    EDI_lang          0.056    0.010    5.373    0.000
    EDI_egender       0.163    0.008   19.888    0.000
    G3_Bckgrnd_BrO    0.182    0.020    8.981    0.000
  s ~                                                 
    Lw_r_t_rsk_LnC    0.027    0.005    5.562    0.000
    SES               0.022    0.004    5.513    0.000
    EDI_lang          0.127    0.005   25.912    0.000
    EDI_egender       0.057    0.004   14.704    0.000
    G3_Bckgrnd_BrO    0.048    0.010    5.065    0.000

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
 .i ~~                                                
   .s                -0.032    0.003   -9.746    0.000

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .G3_Theta_Read     0.000                           
   .G6_Theta_Read     0.000                           
   .G10_Thet_Ltrcy    0.000                           
   .i                -0.035    0.009   -4.106    0.000
   .s                -0.079    0.004  -19.378    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .G3_Theta_Read     0.315    0.006   53.435    0.000
   .G6_Theta_Read     0.333    0.003  103.024    0.000
   .G10_Thet_Ltrcy    0.224    0.006   38.980    0.000
   .i                 0.566    0.007   85.822    0.000
   .s                 0.051    0.003   17.805    0.000
```

Can you please help me understand if the Intercepts section -- for .i (-.035) and .s (-.079), are these grand mean, or are they in absence of the dummy variables (i.e., when dummy variables are held at 0)?

Also, can you please confirm that Regressions section, the parameter estimates for each covariate are in relation to the "Intercepts" (again, .i (-.035) and .s (-.079))... that is, the estimates are to be added or subtracted from those values as in multiple regression with dummy variables? For example, the covariate Lw_r_t_rsk_LnC influences the intercept at -.771, which means the actual estimate of the intercept for subjects who are coded "1" for the variable Lw_r_t_rsk_LnC would be (-.771)+(-.035)?

I attempted to post [here](https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/issues/284) last week but am still hoping to hear from the community. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the coefficients are interpreted in the same way as in conventional linear regression. The intercept coefficient estimates for the i and s factors give the expected values (means) of i and s when all covariates (dummies) take on the value of zero.

The slope coefficient estimates give the mean differences (differences in mean intercepts and differences in mean slopes) between the two groups (adjusted for the presence of the other dummies/covariates/predictors).

Comment: Thank you so much Christian!